# Is there a difference in meaning between "lounging" and "relaxing" on a beach?

Tags: difference

> - I'd like to **lounge** on the beach.
> - I'd like to **relax** on the beach.

Do the two sentences convey slightly different meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could describe the exact same thing, but with slightly different focus.

With "I'd like to lounge on the beach", the focus is on what you're going to be doing, which is probably things like lying on the sand, floating in the water, drinking sweet drinks, reading a book, listening to music, and so on.

With "I'd like to relax on the beach", the focus is on the benefits you're getting from doing these things: they are relaxing, and reduce your stress.

Someone with a relatively stress-free life, not needing to work, not having responsibilities or serious problems might do these things on the beach simply because they enjoy them. This is lounging.

Someone else with a busy life full of responsibilities and problems might do these same things to help them de-stress. This is relaxing.

Answer (score 0):

In general, "lounge" is more specific and descriptive of a word than "relax" is.

"[Lounge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lounge)" is often paired in the phrase "[to lounge around](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lounge+around)", which means nearly the equivalent of "to be lazy" and conveys more idle laziness.  It is used more often as a negative trait.

"[Relax](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relax)" feels more like a conscious choice — perhaps sun tanning or sipping a cold drink — and is generally viewed positively.